# Fixing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

I have to run this code for my class, most of what we use is java, I don't really know c++, but the code I have to run is c++, so I'm finding it difficult to debug or know what's going wrong. To compile it, I'm using a unix virtual machine. I've compiled it and have the a.out file in my directory. When I run the a.out file it says "segmentation fault". I've read that means it's trying to access something it can't, but I don't know what that would be. Is it a problem with the code they gave us, or could it be something like a setting on my machine?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int N;
  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);
  vector<double> data(N);
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    data[i] = rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
  }
  sort(data.begin(), data.end());
  copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout,"\n"));
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking your `a.out`? Did you forget to specify the command line argument? What's the value of `argc`?

Comment: you need to pass an argument to your executable.
`sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);`

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine. Here is a live test of your code:  https://segfault.stensal.com/a/KPIOio3htesH6mYZ,   feel free to use it to trouble shoot segfault.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a matter of how you invoke the compiled binary. Say the executable is `a.out`, you should execute the program as

```
./a.out 42
```

as in this snippet

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);
```

the size of the `std::vector` is parsed from the command line arguments. If you don't pass any arguments, `argv` has only one element (the executable name), and `argv[1]` is an out of bounds access, yielding undefined behavior. Note that you can use the `argc` variable to do some rudimentary error handling up front:

```
int N = 42; // some sensible default value

if (argc == 2)
   sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);
```

This still won't protect you from trouble if the given argument is not parsable as an integer, but if you want to get into this, consider using a library for parsing command line options.

Comment: Technically, `arg[1]` itself is not out of bounds, since there is a terminal argument, but will contain a nullptr which can't be dereferenced.

Comment: @Eljay Interesting, is that guaranteed? That means `argc` is somewhat redundant?

Comment: I believe it is guaranteed, but I'm not sure what standard is authoritative, so I cannot cite chapter-and-verse.  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html

Comment: @lubgr, argc can be recomputed from the terminal argument.  It is not part of C specification, but it's how Linux kernel creates a process with an executable. I don't know whether it's true or not for other OS.